# How to create unit test for UISceneConnectionOptions?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

Is there a way to set the launch URL and source application property of connectionOptions/UISceneConnectionOptions for testing SceneDelegate? I see that the properties of UISceneConnectionOptions are all read-only but I was wondering if there are any workarounds to this. My project has an existing unit test for AppDelegate's launchOptions, and is able to set the url and source application, but I'm getting errors that the property is 'get' only with connectionOptions.